# Convert a mysql date to NSDate then check how many days between

Tags: swift, cocoa, date, nsdate

I'm having problems with NSDate in Swift.

1. I JSON a date formatted in Y-m-d from my database. This is stored as a string called survey_date
2. I then convert the string to a NSDate using dateFormatter
3. I want to work out the amount of days between the survey_date and NOW

Error in my script is endDate is ambiguous expression without more context.

Here is my script:

```
var survey_date = prefs.valueForKey("SURVEY_DATE") as! String

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(survey_date) as NSDate!
        let outputDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

        println(outputDate)

        let start = outputDate
        let end = NSDate()

        let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(start)!
        let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(end)!

        let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

        let unit:NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay

        let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)

        println(components)
```

Secondly, I also want to be able to convert the date when possible to a different format - for example d m, Y. This is pretty simple to do in PHP but I can't find a way of doing it in Swift? I don't want to have to send extra data through JSON (i.e. create a $formatted_date) but it looks like this is my only option (which I know is messy and I will get told off for!)

Comment: You need two date formatters, one to read the input string, and another to convert the date object to a string using the different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a compiler error in

```
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(end)!
```

because `dateFromString()` is called with a *date* instead of a *string*,
which makes no sense.

Your computation is a bit too complicated, you can shorten it to

```
let survey_date = "2015-05-01"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(survey_date) {
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = cal.components(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)
    let days = components.day
    println(days)

} else {
    println("invalid input")
}
```

If you want to convert the date into a different format then
(as Leo already said in a comment), use `stringFromDate()` with
a second date formatter, e.g.

```
let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "d MM, Y"
let formattedStartDate = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(startDate)
println(formattedStartDate)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I am now having another issue whereby my date from mysql is 2015-27-05 (GMT+1 timezone - BST) which outputting as 2015-05-26 23:00:00 +0000. How can I get this to correct and will the problem occur later in the year when the timezones change?

Comment: @tomantford: NSDate represents an absolute point in time and does not have a time zone. Printing an NSDate always shows the value in GMT. In your case `2015-27-05` in GMT+1 is *the same point in time* as `2015-05-26 23:00:00 +0000`. In short: everything's OK.

Comment: This is affecting the days count - my date 2015-27-05 is interpreted as 2015-26-05 and therefore my day count is 5 when it should be 6

Comment: I should point out I've swapped the start and end dates around - my endDate is the date of the survey which is the date from mysql (27th) but showing as 26th

Comment: In order to avoid time zone confusion, `NSDate` always stores its values as GMT dates/times; you have to use `NSDateFormatter` and its `timeZone` property to display dates and times for a specified time zone.

In many cases, using the current calendar's time zone (which is determined by the user's settings) should work:

    `dateFormatter.timeZone = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().timeZone`

Comment: @tomantford: It should not affect the computation because all calendrical calculations (such as `cal.components(...)` ) are done in your local time zone by default. – But if the starting date is `NSDate()` then the problem is that the difference is computed from the current date+time (e.g. today 11am), and you probably want `let startDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())`.

Comment: Perfect @MartinR! I'm now getting the expected 6 day gap. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's something you may find handy.** I was working on an app that did a lot of date calculations, and therefore was making lots of calls to `NSCalendar`'s `components(_:fromDate:toDate:options:)` method. This doesn't feel terribly Swift-like, so I overloaded the `-` operator to do date subtractions:

```
func -(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> NSDateComponents
{
  let components: NSCalendarUnit =
    .CalendarUnitSecond |
    .CalendarUnitMinute |
    .CalendarUnitHour   |
    .CalendarUnitDay
  return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(components,
    fromDate: rhs,
    toDate: lhs,
    options: nil)
}
```

This lets you find the difference between any two dates/times by simple subtraction. Here's a quick example:

```
// MySQL date formatter
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// Let's create a couple of dates that we know are one day apart
let christmas2015 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-12-25")!
let christmasEve2015 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-12-24")!

let difference = christmas2015 - christmasEve2015
let daysBetween = difference.day // this value is 1
```